# Como chamar uma variável que está em outro arquivo?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um arquivo "Y.php" que retorna em um dos inputs, o cálculo resultante de outros inputs dentro deste mesmo arquivo, faço isto usando Jquery e está funcionando 100%.

Porém, gostaria de usar o resultado deste cálculo que está armazenado na variável "X" em uma outra input contida no arquivo "Z.php". Ou seja, quero usar o valor desta input (contida em "Z.php") como resultado de outra input contida no arquivo "Y.php".

Como faço isso com JavaScript?

```
require ('apNaoCirculantes.php'); //arquivo onde está a input na qual desejo pegar o valor
            var totaldeparred; // é o variável da input
            var campo16; // já estou no arquivo Z.PHP
            campo16 === totaldeparred;
            $("#depreciacao1").maskMoney('mask', totaldeparred); //minha input #depreciacao1 recebe o valor contido em totaldeparred
```

É isso?

Comment: Vc pode fazer isso via include ou Ajax? Sua pergunta ficou meio distante.

Comment: Tanto faz, posso testar a solução que for mais simples?

Comment: Então a forma mais fácil é fazer um include. Assim o input com o valor que vc quer pegar vai estar na mesma página e pode pegar esse resultado com  JS.

Comment: Pode citar um exemplo deste include?

Comment: `require('pagina.php');`

Comment: Pelo que entendi, vc quer abrir a página Z.php e pegar o valor contido num input da página Y.php, é isso?

Comment: sim, quero o valor da input que está em Y.php e colocá-lo na input contida em Z.php.

Comment: Isso eu entendi. Mas a página que vc quer abrir é a Z.php?

Comment: Sim, exatamente.

Comment: Vou elaborar uma resposta com o conceito disso, já que não tem código exato, aí vc testa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça um include do arquivo Y.php no início do `<body>` página Z.php:

```
<?php require('Y.php'); ?>
```

Em seguida pegue o valor do `<input>` pelo `id` (se o input tem um `id`) desejado vindo da página Y.php e coloque no `<input>` da página Z.php:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("id_do_input_em_Z.php").value = document.getElementById("id_do_input_em_Y.php").value;
</script>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. obrigado.